# RewriteCond always match incorrectly

Tags: rewrite, rewritecond

If I write:

```
<?php
echo "SCRIPT_NAME: ".@$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']."<br />";
?>
```

SCRIPT_NAME: /index.php

The line above is showed.

I'm using these rewrite lines

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_NAME} !^/index\.php$
RewriteRule .* http://example.com/404 [L]
```

I have checked:

http://example.com/foo

http://example.com/bar

http://example.com/hdhd

The RewriteCond is matched then I'm being redirect to 404

```
[03/Aug/2013:13:07:48 +0200] [example.com/sid#23c3710][rid#263afe8/initial] (4) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/] RewriteCond: input='' pattern='!^/index\\.php$' => matched
[03/Aug/2013:13:07:48 +0200] [example.com/sid#23c3710][rid#263afe8/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/] rewrite '404' -> 'http://example.com/404'
[03/Aug/2013:13:07:48 +0200] [example.com/sid#23c3710][rid#263afe8/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/] implicitly forcing redirect (rc=302) with http://example.com/404
[03/Aug/2013:13:07:48 +0200] [example.com/sid#23c3710][rid#263afe8/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/] escaping http://example.com/404 for redirect
[03/Aug/2013:13:07:48 +0200] [example.com/sid#23c3710][rid#263afe8/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/] redirect to http://example.com/404 [REDIRECT/302]
```

But if I use example.com/index.php/nnn or
example.com/index.php

I'm still being redirected

```
[03/Aug/2013:13:10:41 +0200] [example.com/sid#23c3710][rid#263eff8/initial] (4) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/] RewriteCond: input='' pattern='!^/index\\.php$' => matched
[03/Aug/2013:13:10:41 +0200] [example.com/sid#23c3710][rid#263eff8/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/] rewrite '404' -> 'http://example.com/404'
[03/Aug/2013:13:10:41 +0200] [example.com/sid#23c3710][rid#263eff8/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/] implicitly forcing redirect (rc=302) with http://example.com/404
[03/Aug/2013:13:10:41 +0200] [example.com/sid#23c3710][rid#263eff8/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/] escaping http://example.com/404 for redirect
[03/Aug/2013:13:10:41 +0200] [example.com/sid#23c3710][rid#263eff8/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/] redirect to http://example.com/404 [REDIRECT/302
```

I can't see anything at input='', it is empty at each request. Then never will be different like the pattern, then always will match

Any suggestion?

Comment: What would you like to be done ? if index.php redirect to 404, other query serve the file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apache variable you want is called `%{SCRI­PT_­FIL­ENAME}`.

In PHP's `$_SERVER` super global, both `SCRIPT_NAME` and `SCRIPT_FILENAME` exist but in Apache, only `%{SCRIPT_FILENAME}` exists.

It's not clear from [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) exactly what each of the PHP variables contains but in my testing, `SCRIPT_FILENAME` is a full filesystem path and `SCRIPT_NAME` is either the path from the document root or the path component of the URL.

Comment: yes, with SCRIPT_FILENAME works like I expected.